# one C# sql injection method in asp.net to multiple websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I have multiple websites,
some of them get parameters from a POST , some has JQuery AJAX Handlers, some in querystring, some on onclick asp:Button or ImageButton..

I want to make one method that I can place in all of my website, that will deal with all.
I made this method :

```
private void Si()
{     
    foreach (String key in Request.Params)
    {
        string temp = Request[key];

        string[] array_split_item = new string[] { "–", ";", "/*", "*/", "@@", "char", "nchar", "varchar", "nvarchar", "alter", "begin", "cast", "create", "cursor", "declare", "delete", "drop", "end", "exec", "execute", "fetch", "insert", "kill", "open", "select", "sys", "sysobjects", "syscolumns", "table", "update", "<script", "<//script>", "‘" };


        foreach (string strItem in array_split_item)
        {
            temp = temp.ToLower().Replace(strItem.ToLower(), "");
        }
    }
}
```

2 questions though:

1. is it the best way to make this kind of method?
2. is it possible to know if someone has been "caught" in this method trying to inject something ?if so , how ?

Thanks!

Comment: "is it the best way to make this kind of method?" No.  Used parameterized queries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that's a horrible way to "protect" against SQL injection. Don't do it. Not only is it horribly insecure (you'll never catch *everything*), it also breaks user input badly. Why shouldn't a user be allowed to use the words "after", "etc" etc? Those are incredibly common words.

Use parametrized queries and it becomes impossible to inject any code via user input.

Comment: I could not help myself, but think about all the comical outputs that this approach can give, if you apply it to say emails. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use parameterized queries.

Please go through this link

http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad way to protect yourself. Thus simple things should already be validated by asp.net itself.

Like mentioned: use parametrized queries.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 steps suggested to do in order to avoid sql injection attacks:
1. use parameters in your sql requests
2. use HTML encoding/decoding

Comment: HTML encoding protects against XSS, not SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all the posters who have insisted that you use parameterized queries.  That's the way to go.

In addition I'd like to point out something else.  What you are engaging in is know as black list validation, where you try to think of all the things a hacker will think of and prevent them from being entered.  The problem with black listing things is that hackers have a lot more time on their hands to figure these things out.  The preferred validation method is white list validation-- where you decide which inputs are allowed (instead of what is disallowed).  This would probably end up being page-specific.  You can't write a general routine for that.